# Image display incorrect on toolstrip

Tags: c#, .net

I use a 32-bit image & use it as a value for Image property of ToolStripButton. But I don't know why it displays unlike the original one.
This is the screenshot:

[http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/7668/34711163.png http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/7668/34711163.png](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/7668/34711163.png)

And my project:
http://www.mediafire.com/?3mzmf5r5nnx

Please help me to find the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opened the 'button_9.png' in Paint.NET and it seems like the 'white glass' of the magnifier is semi-transparent.

So you have to edit the image that the magnifier has an opaque backcolor.